# Javascript returning array into index[0] of return function array

Tags: javascript

Completely new to javascript, attempting to do a webGL project.

Here is what I am working towards in the end, the idea is to have two for loops

```
// Create the vertex data for a grid to be drawn
function createGrid(gl, x, y) {
    var vertexBuffer;
    vertexBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBuffer);
    var matrix= []
    for(var i = 0, i < x, ++i)
    {
        for(var j = 0, i < y, ++j)
        {
            matrix.push(createSquare(i,j))
        }
    }
     gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(matrix), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
     var grid = {buffer:vertexBuffer, vertSize:3, nVerts:matrix.length, primtype:gl.TRIANGLE_STRIP};

     return grid;
}
```

I am trying to dynamically create a wall of squares essentially. I have two functions.

```
// Create the vertex data for a square to be drawn
function createSquare(gl, x, y) {

    var square = [  x+ .5, y+ .5,  0.0,
                    x+ -.5, y+ .5,  0.0,
                    x+ .5,y+ -.5,  0.0,
                    x+ -.5,y+ -.5,  0.0];

    return square;
}

 // Create the vertex data for a grid to be drawn
function createGrid(gl, x, y) {
    var vertexBuffer;
    vertexBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBuffer);

    var matrix= []
    matrix.push(createSquare(gl,x,y ));

    var numVerts = matrix.length;
     alert(matrix[0]);

     gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(matrix), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
    var grid = {buffer:vertexBuffer, vertSize:3, nVerts:numVerts, primtype:gl.TRIANGLE_STRIP};

    return grid;
}
```

What is messing me up is the line

```
matrix.push(createSquare(gl,x,y ));
```

I was expecting to get matrixpopulated with the same array that was created in createSquare. However, all the the items in my square object are in the first index of matrix, assuming in string format. Searched and all I saw were people not having their array returned at all.

```
matrix[0] = 1.5,0.5,0,0.5,0.5,0,1.5,-0.5,0,0.5,-0.5,0 and
matrix[1] = undefined
```

EDIT: I get it now, matrix[0] contains the array object. This is also why I tried array.concat() earlier but then I was in the same situation as others where the array didn't return at all. array.push() was the only function that returned me anything.

Comment: `grid = createSquare(gl, x, y);`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of pushing `createSquare(gl,x,y)` into grid just set grid equal to it so:

```
grid = createSquare(gl, x, y);
```

Comment: I know I made a bunch of edits, but I always had in there that I want to have a bunch of squares inside of grid.

Comment: Well it's not working the way I was expecting, but I may just work around it altogether and drop the createSquare() function and put it all in createGrid()

Comment: What is not working the way you wanted. Is it creating an array and if so what is wrong with that array.

Comment: I was expecting to return from createSquare() and have matrix.size = 12 due to four vertices having been inserted. concat()(instead of push) looks like it should have worked this way but then matrix is completely empty.

Comment: So you tried `matrix.concat(createSquare(gl, x, y));`

Comment: Yeh and matrix[0] came back as undefined, but matrix = matrix.concat(createSquare(gl,x,y)) returned 12 individual items. Which is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You are defining your `grid` variable as an array, and then pushing a square into it, as the way it is, grid will be always an array with length === 1, if You just replace:

```
grid.push(createSquare(gl,x,y ));
```

with:

```
grid = createSquare(gl,x,y);
```

It should work as you want.

Also note that you are redefining `grid` in the following line:

```
var grid = {buffer:vertexBuffer, vertSize:3, nVerts:numVerts, primtype:gl.TRIANGLE_STRIP};
```

Maybe thats intended, but I comment it to you so that you know.

Comment: the var grid = [buffer... wasn't intended, but it wasn't the cause of the issue. Thanks though, edited it in my code.

Comment: It was just a heads up. The first part of my answer is a possible fix.

Comment: But I want to push many squares onto grid(now called matrix) in the form of four sets of vertices per square.

Answer (score 0):

So the answer was.....

```
matrix = matrix.concat(createSquare(x,y));
```

When I was goofing around earlier I was just using

```
matrix.concat(createSquare(x,y));
```

...and it didn't complain.

Answer (score 0):

The issue in your original code is `createSquare` returns an array. So the line

```
matrix.push(createSquare(i,j))
```

is making an array of arrays. But `new Float32Array(matrix)` from the line

```
gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(matrix), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
```

expects a single array, not an array of arrays. There are multiple ways to fix this. The simplest is to change this like

```
matrix.push(createSquare(i,j))
```

to this

```
matrix = matrix.concat(createSquare(i,j))
```

The `concat` function takes the array you have and the arrays you pass it and concatenates them into a **new array**. In other words, a single line `matrix.concat(someArray)` will do nothing because it will make a new array but because that array is not assigned to a variable it's lost immediately.

But note that is a slow solution. Maybe it's fast enough for your needs?

The reason it's slow is because every time you concat a bunch of work needs to be done. Every element from the previous 2 arrays needs to copied to a new array. So for example lets say you made a 1000 squares. The code would be doing

```
 newArray = arrayOf0Elements  + arrayOf12Elements;
 newArray = arrayOf12Elements + arrayOf12Elements;
 newArray = arrayOf24Elements + arrayOf12Elements;
 newArray = arrayOf36Elements + arrayOf12Elements;
 newArray = arrayOf48Elements + arrayOf12Elements;
 ...
 newArray = arrayof11964Elements + arrayOf12Elements;
 newArray = arrayof11976Elements + arrayOf12Elements;
 newArray = arrayof11988Elements + arrayOf12Elements;
```

Hopefully you can see why that's slow. That's 6006000 copies that have to happen!

One simple way to make it fast-er is to concat at the end like this. Leave the code exactly as was but add this line

```
 var combinedData = Array.prototype.concat.apply([], matrix);
 gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(combinedData), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
```

This way, in the 1000 square case, you make 1000 squares of 12 elements each. You then concat them all at once. That's only 12000 copies vs the other way which was 6006000 copies.

`Array.prototype.concat` is the bare JavaScript function for concatting arrays.  Calling `apply` lets you pass it an object to operate on, in this case `[]` and then the arguments to it in an array. It's the same as if you had done this

```
var combineData = [].concat(matrix[0], matrix[1], matrix[2], ... matrix[999]);
```

One of the fastest ways would be to create the `Float32Array` at the beginning and pass it into createSquare with an offset like this

```
// Create the vertex data for a square to be drawn
function createSquare(dst, offset, x, y) {

    dst[offset++] = x+ .5;
    dst[offset++] = y+ .5;
    dst[offset++] = 0.0;
    dst[offset++] = x+ -.5;
    dst[offset++] = y+ .5;
    dst[offset++] = 0.0;
    dst[offset++] = x+ .5;
    dst[offset++] = y+ -.5;
    dst[offset++] = 0.0;
    dst[offset++] = x+ -.5;
    dst[offset++] = y+ -.5;
    dst[offset++] = 0.0;

    return offset;
}

// Create the vertex data for a grid to be drawn
function createGrid(gl, x, y) {
    var vertexBuffer;
    vertexBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBuffer);

    // allocate space for all vertices up front
    var matrix = new Float32Array(x * y * 12); 
    var offset = 0;
    for(var i = 0, i < x, ++i)
    {
        for(var j = 0, i < y, ++j)
        {
            offset = createSquare(matrix, offset, i, j))
        }
    }
     gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, matrix, gl.STATIC_DRAW);
     var grid = {buffer:vertexBuffer, vertSize:3, nVerts:matrix.length, primtype:gl.TRIANGLE_STRIP};

     return grid;
}
```

Now there's no concatenation at all and no extra arrays being created.

Which way you choose is up to you. I'd probably pick the middle concat version as it's probably the most flexible because you don't have to compute the number of vertices up front so if you change the number of vertices per square you don't have to change any other code.